# Understanding Google OAuth2 Refresh tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api

I previously worked on an OAuth2 application where the logic was to generate a new access token via refresh token once the old one expired.

Now working with Google APIs, I'm not experiencing the same thing. I have received both an access token and refresh token, and after allowing the access token to expire, I attempt to use the refresh token

```
               var myToken = new TokenResponse
            {
                RefreshToken = sRefreshToken
            };

            var credentials = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
              new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
              {
                  ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                  {
                      ClientId = clientId,
                      ClientSecret = clientSecret
                  }
              }), "user", myToken);

            service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
                ApplicationName = "XYZ",
            });
```

It seems after doing so I can make API calls. But I have tried to retrieve the access/refresh tokens after doing this with:

```
            ACCESS_TOKEN = credentials.Token.AccessToken;
            REFRESH_TOKEN = credentials.Token.RefreshToken;
```

And both the access and refresh tokens are the same as the old ones. I had thought refreshing would generate a new token altogether? Is this not the case?

If the access token expires after 30 minutes and you then just need to pass in the refresh token (but nothing re-generates), what is the point of the refresh token?

Answer (score 1):

> I previously worked on an OAuth2 application where the logic was to generate a new access token via refresh token once the old one expired.

This idea also applies to Google access/refresh tokens. But if you're using the .NET client library (as your code snippet suggests), you don't have to perform the refreshes yourself. You can just continue using the `UserCredential` object and it'll automatically fetch a new access token every ~1h.

Comment: But is the old refresh token continuing to work forever? I want to store the updated values so when I return later I can keep refreshing as necessary.

Comment: Yes, the refresh token stays valid -- Google doesn't invalidate/rotate refresh tokens every time you use them.